# "Answer your own question" asks before I answer bug?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

Recently I came across a problem with Java "getter" methods; I asked for a beginner style answer and received information that I found to be blurry/confusing but it ended up leading me in the right direction. After finding the information that helped I decided to use the "Answer your own post" and create and question worded for beginners to find and an answer that also supplemented this.

When posting my answer (along with the question) it said I had an error and would not let me continue (it was with the program I didn't format correctly). It took me a while to find the problem but I ended up fixing it. By the time I ended up submitting it it was already posted with 7 down votes due to no answer.

Is this a bug or feature? and is there anything I can do to fix it? I also haven't found any problems with my recent searches here.

Comment: I'm also unable to ask the question again because I've reached my limit. Can this be fixed?

Comment: If you got down votes, it having a self-posted answer would not have stopped that. Self-answered questions are subject to the same quality criteria as other questions.

Comment: @TXHX No it was different I had the question and answer but I worded the question so it would flow into the answer. When I clicked post it only posted the question but said I had to fix the answer. I wasn't able to submit both at the same time and because it looked like I had a question that didn't answer anything (even though I was answering it) people down voted it. Then when I fixed the problem and clicked submit it then added the answer. By the time I got there I already had 7 down votes. It posted one thing without he other leading to a diminished quality of content.

Comment: As I said, it being a self-answered question does not change how it should be judged by the community. If your question was bad enough to receive 7 down-votes in the time it took you to fix whatever formatting issue the answer had, then it was a (horrifically) bad question.

Comment: No I get that (you're right) my main point that I'm trying to bring up is that it posted before I answered even though it looked as if it didn't and I wanted to know if it was a feature, bug, etc. I'm not trying to validate my answer I'm confused on what happened.

Comment: What error did you get that prevented you from posting the answer?

Comment: It was a format error with how I put the code in. It said I formatted it wrong and it was with how I had " >'2.5' "